# Solving for $A$ in the matrix identity $P^{-1} A P = D$ - is this how to do it?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

If its given $P^{-1}AP = D$ then can I make $A$ the subject as follows:-

$$\begin{align*}
P^{-1}AP &= D\\
PP^{-1}AP &= PD\\
AP &= PD\\
APP^{-1} &= PDP^{-1}\\
A &= PDP^{-1}
\end{align*}$$

If that's not the way then how to make $A$ the subject? Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Seems good!      $~~~~~~``$

Answer (score 0):

This is valid, yes. (It's also another common way people state the identity when it comes to the topic of diagonalization.) You simply:

- multiplied on both left sides by $P$
- multiplied on both right sides by $P^{-1}$
- noted that $PP^{-1}$ and $P^{-1}P$ are the identity matrix $I$ (and you can do this since matrix multiplication is associative, even if it isn't commutative)
- noted that $MI=IM=M$ for any matrix $M$ where that multiplication is defined

...and simplified accordingly. Hence,

$$D = P^{-1} A P \iff A = PDP^{-1}$$

Comment: Yes that's what I did  thanks man ❤️